# Java regex (java.util.regex). Search for dollar sign

Tags: java, regex, special-characters, dollar-sign

I have a search string.
When it contains a dollar symbol, I want to capture all characters thereafter, but not include the dot, or a subsequent dollar symbol.. The latter would constitute a subsequent match.
So for either of these search strings...:

```
"/bla/$V_N.$XYZ.bla";
"/bla/$V_N.$XYZ;
```

I would want to return:

- V_N
- XYZ

If the search string contains percent symbols, I also want to return what's between the pair of % symbols.

The following regex seems do the trick for that.

```
 "%([^%]*?)%";
```

Inferring:

- Start and end with a %,
- Have a capture group - the ()
- have a character class containing anything except a % symbol, (caret infers not a character)
- repeated - but not greedily *?

Where some languages allow `%1`, `%2`, for capture groups, Java uses `backslash\number` syntax instead. So, this string compiles and generates output.

I suspect the dollar symbol and dot need escaping, as they are special symbols:

- `$` is usually end of string
- `.` is a meta sequence for any character.

I have tried using double backslash symbols.. \

- Both as character classes .e.g. `[^\\.\\$%]`
- and using **OR'd** notation `%|\\$`

in attempts to combine this logic and can't seem to get anything to play ball.

**I wonder if another pair of eyes can see how to solve this conundrum!**

My attempts so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String search = "/bla/$V_N.$XYZ.bla";
        String pattern = "([%\\$])([^%\\.\\$]*?)\\1?";
  /* Either % or $ in first capture group ([%\\$])
   * Second capture group - anything except %, dot or dollar sign
   * non greedy group ( *?)
   * then a backreference to an optional first capture group \\1?
   * Have to use two \, since you escape \ in a Java string.
   */
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(search);
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
          while (m.find()) 
        { 
          for (int i = 0; i<= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                results.add(m.group(i));
          }
        }
        for (String result : results) {
          System.out.println(result);
        }
  }
}
```

The following links may be helpful:

- [An interactive Java playground where you can experiment and copy/paste code](https://repl.it/~).
- [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)
- [Java RegexTester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.htm)
- [Java backreferences](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-regular-expressions/regex-backreferences.html) (The optional backreference `\\1` in the Regex).
- [Link that summarises Regex special characters often found in languages](http://www.tads.org/t3doc/doc/sysman/regex.htm)
- [Java Regex book EPub link](https://epdf.pub/java-regular-expressions-taming-the-javautilregex-enginebb1d05a7e538794b13b753aba70948a355735.html)
- [Regex Info Website](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- [Matcher class in the Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
String search = "/bla/$V_N.$XYZ.bla";
String pattern = "[%$]([^%.$]*)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(search);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
} // => V_N, XYZ
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/TGBOpY) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Thvy2r/1).

**NOTE**

- You do not need an optional `\1?` at the end of the pattern. As it is optional, it does not restrict match context and is redundant (as the negated character class cannot already match neither `$` nor`%`)
- `[%$]([^%.$]*)` matches `%` or `$`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more 
  chars other than `%`, `.` and `$`. You only need Group 1 value, hence, `matcher.group(1)` is used.
- In a [**character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), neither `.` nor `$` are special, thus, they do not need escaping in `[%.$]` or  `[%$]`.

Comment: Think I'd need a non greedy search.

Comment: @JGFMK No, you do not not. The negated character class already does it.

Comment: I suspect this will fail to match pairs (assuming that's a requirement). For example, try `"/bla/$V_N%.$XYZ.bla"` as input

Comment: @ernest_k That does cause a bit of a hiccup in the results. You get an empty capture group. But. luckily the data I have always has either pairs of % signs, or just begins with a $. A dot or a subsequent $ or end of line, can be the end of what I need to capture if the thing starts with the $. I could always safeguard by checking length of group(1) before adding it to my results too.

Comment: @JGFMK If you need to avoid empty strings in the results all you need is a `+` quantifier in the pattern: `String pattern = "[%$]([^%.$]+)";`. I only used `*` because I followed the original pattern logic where `*?` was used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The problem ended up being more complex. I posted another follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827094/java-regex-capture-string-starting-with-single-dollar-but-not-when-it-has-two?noredirect=1#comment103930869_58827094 Wondered if you had any insights for that one?

Comment: @Holger Unfortunately, the current question did not reflect the real requirements. I posted a more sophisticated solution meeting more specific requirements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58833692/3832970).

Comment: I know that there’s a follow-up question, however, there’s a general issue with the statement that optional matches at the end of a pattern are redundant. Whenever you are processing more than the first match, they are relevant.

Comment: @Holger This will only make a difference for consecutive matches, and my suggestion takes into account the OP logic. *Here*, `\1?` is redundant, period, I explained why in my answer. I do not say optional patterns at the end of a pattern are always redundant.