# Java Regex - capture string with single dollar, but not when it has two successive ones

Tags: java, regex, java-8, backreference, capture-group

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821727/java-regex-java-util-regex-search-for-dollar-sign) question earlier.

But that wasn't quite the end of it.
All the rules that applied there still apply.

So  the strings:

- `"%ABC%"` would yield ABC as a result (capture stuff between percent signs)
- as would `"$ABC."` (capture stuff after $, giving up when another dollar or dot appears)
- `"$ABC$XYZ"` would too, and  also give XYZ as a result.

To add a bit more to this:

- `"${ABC}"` should yield ABC too. (ignore curly braces if present - non capture chars perhaps?).
- if you have two successive dollar signs, such as `"$$EFG"`, or `"$${EFG}"`, 
  that should **not** appear in a regex result. (This is where either numbered or named back- references come into play - and the reason I contemplated them as non-capture groups). As I understand it, a group becomes a non-capture group with this syntax `(?:)`.

1) Can I say the % or $ is a non-capture group and reference that by number? Or do only capture groups get allocated numbers?

2) What is the order of the numbering, if you have `((A) (B) (C))`. Is the outer group 1, A 2, B 3 C 4?

I have been look at named groups. Saw the syntax mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415635/495157)

> `(?<name>capturing text)` to define a named group "name"
>
> `\k<name>` to backreference a named group "name"

3) Not sure if a non-capture group can be named in Java? Can someone elucidate?

- More info [here on non capture groups](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/non_capturing_groups.shtml).
- More info here on [lookbehinds](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-regular-expressions/regex-lookbehind.html)
- Similar answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16717823/495157), but didn't quite get me what I wanted. Not sure if there is a back-reference issue in Java.
- Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734977/backreferences-in-lookbehind). But could not get my head around the working version to apply to this.

I have used the exact same Java I had in my original question, except for:

```
String search = "/bla/$V_N.$$XYZ.bla";
String pattern = "(?:(?<oc>[%$]))(?!(\\k<oc>))([^%.$]*)+";
```

This should only result in **V_N**.

I am really struggling with this one, and wondered if someone can help me work out how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Are there restrictions that make simplest solutions non-viable? You could just preprocess the text and remove every instance of `{}` and double `$` with one pass through the text, almost guaranteed to be faster than regex backtracking solution

Comment: Because I have to process the ones with the double $$ separately too.it's a possibility, but  I'd rather get a better appreciation of regex with Java as an outcome of this.

Comment: You may write an expanded regex with multiple capturing groups and only grab those that are not null - `%([^%.]+)%|(?<!\$)\$(?:\{([^{}]+)\}|([^$.]+))`, see https://regex101.com/r/7Q6EAD/1

Comment: A simple group of separate conditions would go a long way to getting an answer. As it is now, its hard to tell what those conditions are. Literals work best, maybe 2 columns: Pass/Fail work the best.

Comment: How about something loose like `(?<=(?<!\$)[%$]\{?)[^%$.\s}{]+`

Comment: I have been thinking about this overnight and wondered if rather than  two sets of regexes  for the $$ and $ version within the same string, the position of the character before the found match (defensively checking if 0), contains a $, I could simplify the regex slightly and break out two sets of results based on that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll accept that. Can see by using Regex101 that non capture groups don't get allocated a number for back referencing.

Comment: The difference between a capturing group and a noncapturing group is that the former’s match can be referenced later-on whereas the latter can not. So it makes no sense to ask for a way to reference a noncapturing group. If you want to reference a group, use a capturing group. That’s what it is for.

Comment: @Holger - it was the negative look behind that WiktorStribiżew gave as a solution that was the correct way to go when dealing with the double $ symbol conundrum. I became confusied, thinking the back referencing it with \\1 or a named group - in conjunction with  (?!\1) would have been a way to solve it. (per answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16717823/495157 ) But since I didn't want to capture the $ symbol, that thinking muddied the waters. Couldn't think of elegant way to deal with complex groups within groups and knowing which ones to get.

Comment: I see; you asked for the numbering of nested groups. The answer is simple. The order of the opening brackets of the capturing groups matters.

Comment: @Holger - My assumption was correct. And I confirmed that with a comment below the answer Wiktor gave.

Comment: Well, yes. But for the next time, don’t make assumptions, just go directly to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)…

Comment: Cheers for link - have bookmarked that section for future reference ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write a little bit more verbose regex with multiple capturing groups and only grab those that are not `null`, or plainly concatenate the found group values since there will be always only one of them initialized upon each match:

```
%([^%.]+)%|(?<!\$)\$(?:\{([^{}]+)\}|([^$.]+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Q6EAD/1).

**Details**

- `%([^%.]+)%` - `%`, Group 1: one or more chars other than `%` and `.`, then a `%` is consumed
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\$)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location in string that is not immediately preceded with `$`
- `\$` - a `$`
- `(?:` - start of the non-capturing container group matching either of:

  - `\{([^{}]+)\}` - `{`, Group 2: any one or more chars other than `{` and `}`, then `}` is consumed
  - `|` - or
  - `([^$.]+)` - Group 3: 1 or more chars other than `$` and `.`
- `)` - end of the non-capturing container group.

[Java usage](https://ideone.com/kaKfBz):

```
String regex = "%([^%.]+)%|(?<!\\$)\\$(?:\\{([^\\{}]+)\\}|([^$.\\s]+))";
String string = "%ABC%\n$ABC.\n$ABC$XYZ  ${ABC}\n\n$$EFG $${EFG}.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    results.add(Objects.toString(m.group(1),"") + 
        Objects.toString(m.group(2),"") + 
        Objects.toString(m.group(3),""));
}
System.out.println(results); // => [ABC, ABC, ABC, XYZ, ABC]
```

Mind that in regular Java string literals, `\` should be escaped (i.e. `\\`) to introduce a single *literal* backslash that is used as part of *regex escapes*.

Comment: To anyone else wanting answers to the other questions I posed. Non-capture groups can't be back-referenced  by either number Q1 or name  Q3. And for Q2, regex101.com provides a nice colour coded answer and you can hover over the regex expression to determine that. My assumption was correct.

Comment: Just wish Java would follow C# and preface double quotes with @ character, so things like \ don't need escaping! ;-) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/index (Verbatim string literals)

Comment: Really like the Objects.toString() solution. Had forgotten too that you always have a capture group 0 too. Just been reading up about that in *Ken Kousen's* **Modern Java Recipes** too. Thx to @Holger for the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg

Comment: @JGFMK Right, Java does not support raw string literals. Scala, Koltin, Groovy do have something similar (triple quoted string literals, slashy strings), but Java lags behind here.